# edit contact us to send email to an address based on drop down

Tags: contact-us

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1 and want to have a drop down added to the contact us page labeled "subject" then based on what subject was selected would determine which email address the contact us page sends an email to.

So What I have done is added the below code to my form.phtml page

```
        <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Subject') ?>">
                             <option value="or@foo.com">Order Information</option>
                             <option value="pro@foo.com">Product Information</option>
                             <option value="acct@foo.com">Account Information</option>
                             <option value="support@foo.com">Wholesale Information</option>
                             <option value="retail@foo.com">General Feedback or Question</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </li>
```

I then copied 
app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php 
to 
app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

I then edited the code to reflect the below

```
             $emailthisto = $post['subject'];
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    /* Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT), */
                    $emailthisto,
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
```

However my code does not seem to work in the sense that the correct email address does not get sent the email??

Comment: is your select inside <form> ? Try to look at Mage::log(   Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()   );

Comment: Yes my select drop down is inside the <form> tag it almost seems like Magento is not reading the controller from the app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php location because when I test the contact us page it still sends to the email address listed in the magento configuration admin page and if anything I would think the contact page would eaither send to the email address that is associated with the $emailthisto variable or not send an email at all?

Comment: Using Mage::log determine which controller file you are using. Try to use controller rewrite as magento recommend it.